# How can I use os.system() as a variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get a filename remove the extension and use the string as a variable to search for tvshow using tmdbv3api

```
someshow = os.system("ls ./ | grep '.mkv' | sed 's/.\{3\}$// ; s/\./ /g'")


from tmdbv3api import TMDb
from tmdbv3api import TV
tmdb = TMDb()

tv = TV()
show = tv.search(someshow)

for result in show:
   print(result.id)
```

Comment: you're probably better to use `os.listdir('.')` (for `ls`), `.endswith('.mkv')`, and `re` for replacement.  though if you want to go with your subprocess approach, you'd probably use `subprocess.run`

Comment: thanks for your comment i started using python yesterday and learnt by migrating one of my bash scripts over, I think I've been cheating and not using python properly, I've been using os.system() for most things as that's what I feel comfortable with, I will probably have to read up on endswith and re

Answer (score 0):

Python has a library just to deal with paths.  I would find some other way to deal with the output than to print the id.

```
from pathlib import Path
from tmdbv3api import TMDb
from tmdbv3api import TV
tmdb = TMDb()

tv = TV()

mkv_files = Path('.').glob('*.mkv')
for mkv_file in mkv_files:
    show = tv.search(mkv_file.stem)
    for result in show:
        print(result.id)
```